# Could not find rake-10.5.0 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rbenv

i tried to deployed my rails app following this page.

https://gorails.com/deploy/ubuntu/14.04

So everything seems fine but in the end when i ran

```
cap production deploy
```

It didn't work i got this on my page.

```
Please read the Passenger log file to find the details of the error.
```

So i opened that file and i got this

```
Could not find rake-10.5.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
<pre>  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:94:in `block in materialize'
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:87:in `map!'
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:87:in `materialize'
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:137:in `specs'
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:182:in `specs_for'
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:171:in `requested_specs'
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs'
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup'
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:92:in `setup'
  /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/setup.rb:18:in `&lt;top (required)&gt;'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:430:in `activate_gem'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:297:in `block in run_load_path_setup_code'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:435:in `running_bundler'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:296:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:100:in `preload_app'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:156:in `&lt;module:App&gt;'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `&lt;module:PhusionPassenger&gt;'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `&lt;main&gt;'</pre>
```

How can i fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you run `bundle install`?

Comment: @dharam where can i run it? i tried at home and i got this. 
Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory

Comment: Where ever you are running `cap production deploy`

Comment: Check the version of  `rake` gem in your `gemfile`. Also check the gem versions via `bundle exec gem list rake` and `gem list rake`. You might have version mismatch between system gems and bundler gems.

Comment: @Dharam cap production deploy was ran on my local to pull the data to the server.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered some like error before, sometimes it needs to put the g**em 'rake'** directly on **Gemfile**. Then run the bundle/bundle install.